# Refresh the page after first load but not if I refresh it again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to reload my html page just after it loads for the first time, but not to reload if page is refreshed. What I have done is:

```
 window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
   }
```

But with this approach if I refresh the page it gets reloaded which I don't want. Are there any solutions to avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page the first time it loads?

Comment: because in mozilla firefox my some functionality is not worked which is at home page when page loads first time.but if i refresh page it works absolutely fine as per need. and also it works fine with other browsers.

Comment: Then you should investigate and fix that problem, instead of introducing a new one.

Comment: Hmm.. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to fix what's not working in Firefox, not create this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage` to achieve this.

Try:

```
alert("page load")
if(localStorage.getItem("reload") != "1"){
    localStorage.setItem("reload","1");
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
}
else{
    localStorage.removeItem("reload");
}
```

Comment: Just to note, this will not work on IE7 or below or iOS safari [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, but how do you prevent reloading on all browsers but Firefox?

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("loaded") < 0) {
        window.location = window.location.href + '?loaded=1'
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cookie and check