# Calling jquery function in the body

Tags: jquery

I want to call this jquery function:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("gamila-secret") < 0) {
        window.location = window.location.href + '?gamila-secret';
    }
});
```

in my html code in the body, so it will be here: `<body onload="*call the function here*">`.
I'm trying to give the function a name like "reloader();" and call it in the body, but how can I do that?

Comment: what doesn't work using ready handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by your option

**in html**

```
<body onload="call()">
```

**In JS**

```
<script>
function call()
{
  if (location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("gamila-secret") < 0) {
    location = location.href + '?gamila-secret';
  }
}
</script>
```

**but the best option if you do with jQuery**

**in html**

```
<body >
//no need to call function
```

**in JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("gamila-secret") < 0) {
    location = location.href + '?gamila-secret';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may define it as function, and call it in such a way, but this is a very bad design example.

Instead, use $(document).ready(function(){...}) syntax.

Anywhere in header or body:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("gamila-secret") < 0) {
    location = location.href + '?gamila-secret';
  }
});
```

If that does not suit you, you may do something like this:

```
window.app_my_listener = function() {
  if (location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("gamila-secret") < 0) {
    location = location.href + '?gamila-secret';
  }
};
body onload="app_my_listener()"
```

But please, don't do that. Every time you directly inject javascript in html God kills a kitten.

Comment: That did not help me, I want to call it in the body, I want to use the `onload=""`

Comment: What is the usecase? Why $.ready() form does not suit you?
Anyways, I updated the answer.